# Can't see events on Flurry, but getting no errors, using Android Flurry SDK 5.60

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am trying to implement Flurry in a new version of our app, but get no events sent through to the Flurry console/site.

I am using the Flurry SDK 5.60 and have tried lots of different things, and I get `Analytics report sent` message in my logs which would make me think everything is working.

To test, I am changing the app version number, and I can see in Event Logs on the Flurry site/console that the new version number appears about 5-10 mins after I use the app, except it says there are no events under that version.

I am setting up Flurry in an extended Application class in onCreate

```
public class App extends Application {

public static final String KEY = "FD**************QZ";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
    FlurryAgent.init(this, KEY);

}
```

}

Then, in my application I use FlurryAgent.LogEvent() to send events

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = OneFragment.newInstance("ONE");
        FlurryAgent.logEvent("ONE PRESSED");
        break;
    default:
        fragment = TwoFragment.newInstance("TWO");
        FlurryAgent.logEvent("TWO PRESSED");
        break;
}
```

Below is my logs for a test run of the app. I start it, click my buttons to send the messages, then I close the app (swipe it away in the recents list) and start it again, to force send the report. Everything in that log looks fine to me?!

```
08-04 12:12:22.737  14841-14865/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Flurry session paused for context:com.nap.jebise.MainActivity@95bd500
08-04 12:12:25.447  15415-15433/com.nap.jebise I/FlurryAgent﹕ New main file also not found. returning..
08-04 12:12:25.457  15415-15433/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Flurry session started for context:com.nap.jebise.MainActivity@95bd500
08-04 12:12:25.457  15415-15433/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Flurry session resumed for context:com.nap.jebise.MainActivity@95bd500
08-04 12:12:25.547  15415-15433/com.nap.jebise D/FlurryAgent﹕ Referrer file contents: null
08-04 12:12:28.537  15415-15415/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Event count started: ONE PRESSED
08-04 12:12:28.677  15415-15446/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Analytics report sent.
08-04 12:12:29.757  15415-15415/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Event count started: TWO PRESSED
08-04 12:12:30.907  15415-15415/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Event count incremented: ONE PRESSED
08-04 12:12:32.707  15415-15415/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Event count incremented: ONE PRESSED
08-04 12:12:34.397  15415-15433/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Flurry session paused for context:com.nap.jebise.MainActivity@95bd500
08-04 12:12:37.997  15910-15928/com.nap.jebise I/FlurryAgent﹕ New main file also not found. returning..
08-04 12:12:37.997  15910-15928/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Flurry session started for context:com.nap.jebise.MainActivity@95bd500
08-04 12:12:37.997  15910-15928/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Flurry session resumed for context:com.nap.jebise.MainActivity@95bd500
08-04 12:12:38.087  15910-15928/com.nap.jebise D/FlurryAgent﹕ Referrer file contents: null
08-04 12:12:41.067  15910-15945/com.nap.jebise W/FlurryAgent﹕ Analytics report sent.
```

I'm a little concerned at what `New main file also not found. returning..` and `Referrer file contents: null` might mean, but can't find anything about either of those through Google.

Note: We started out not using Google Play services as it says it's only needed for ads, which we're not going to use. I've also added this as well, and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed this.

We had hit our event limit of 300 unique events so all the new ones I was sending weren't getting through. That's why the new version id was getting through, but we were seeing no events. A simple test using an old event name would have spotted this hours ago.

Oh well, live and learn...

Comment: To avoid this in the future, I would suggest grouping your event names. For instance, you have events called "ONE PRESSED" and "TWO PRESSED". You could instead of one event called "PRESSED" and pass in what was pressed as a parameter.

Comment: That was just test data, it was never going to be our final event name. Also, it wouldn't have mattered what they were called or if we had grouped them all into one event, it still wouldn't have made it through as we had reached our 300 event limit